# Modify Access 2010 Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have been successfully using the following Access 2010 query to retrieve data from a large (more than a million records) csv database containing the expenses of several thousand organization.  This query produces a long column of numbers organized by LINE_NUM (line number between 00100 and 10099),  and a total for each organization (line number 10100):

```
SELECT
   [1995_1].RPT_REC_NUM,
   [1995_1].PRVDR_NUM,
   [1995_2].WKSHT_CD,
   [1995_2].LINE_NUM,
   [1995_2].CLMN_NUM,
   [1995_2].ITM_VAL_NUM
FROM 1995_1
INNER JOIN 1995_2
ON [1995_1].RPT_REC_NUM = [1995_2].RPT_REC_NUM
WHERE
   ((([1995_2].WKSHT_CD)="A000000") AND (Not ([1995_2].LINE_NUM)="09500") AND
   (([1995_2].CLMN_NUM)="0100" Or ([1995_2].CLMN_NUM)="0200"))
ORDER BY [1995_1].RPT_REC_NUM, [1995_1].PRVDR_NUM, [1995_2].LINE_NUM;
```

I would like to add a statement to the query that tests and returns only those organizations where the sum of lines `( 00100-10099) =sum(10100)`.

So far I have been unable to edit the query to accomplish this goal.

```
RPT_REC_NUM|WKSHT_CD|LINE_NUM|CLMN_NUM|ITM_VAL_NUM
38897   A000000 100 600 -58202
38897   A000000 200 200 98030
38897   A000000 200 600 8169
38897   A000000 300 200 3445
38897   A000000 400 200 406237
38897   A000000 400 600 22879
38897   A000000 500 100 319063
38897   A000000 500 200 1856092
38897   A000000 500 600 -202
38897   A000000 600 100 1433541
38897   A000000 600 200 3762820
38897   A000000 600 600 -1169298
38897   A000000 700 100 265470
38897   A000000 700 200 551233
38897   A000000 900 100 69663
38897   A000000 900 200 38948
38897   A000000 1000    100 214322
38897   A000000 1000    200 105166
38897   A000000 1100    100 273255
38897   A000000 1100    200 451171
38897   A000000 1100    600 -188629
38897   A000000 1400    100 396603
38897   A000000 1400    200 6961
38897   A000000 1500    100 143603
38897   A000000 1500    200 912099
38897   A000000 1600    200 1059912
38897   A000000 1700    100 240054
38897   A000000 1700    200 83344
38897   A000000 1700    600 -2638
38897   A000000 2500    100 2013226
38897   A000000 2500    200 98046
38897   A000000 2500    600 -2327
38897   A000000 2600    100 551931
38897   A000000 2600    200 23301
38897   A000000 3300    100 196060
38897   A000000 3300    200 13485
38897   A000000 3300    600 -2079
38897   A000000 3700    100 539873
38897   A000000 3700    200 427198
38897   A000000 3800    100 55167
38897   A000000 3800    200 2693
38897   A000000 3900    100 329716
38897   A000000 3900    200 33014
38897   A000000 4000    100 24716
38897   A000000 4000    200 130758
38897   A000000 4000    600 -83333
38897   A000000 4100    100 479582
38897   A000000 4100    200 1662635
38897   A000000 4100    600 -932119
38897   A000000 4300    100 48048
38897   A000000 4300    200 187022
38897   A000000 4300    600 -38404
38897   A000000 4400    100 547169
38897   A000000 4400    200 589613
38897   A000000 4400    600 -83525
38897   A000000 4600    100 49044
38897   A000000 4600    200 88309
38897   A000000 4800    200 73280
38897   A000000 4900    100 189434
38897   A000000 4900    200 48636
38897   A000000 5000    100 5415
38897   A000000 5000    200 546001
38897   A000000 5000    600 -97409
38897   A000000 5300    100 138862
38897   A000000 5300    200 111687
38897   A000000 5300    600 -67989
38897   A000000 5400    100 6129
38897   A000000 5400    200 3758
38897   A000000 5600    600 -2092
38897   A000000 6100    100 629731
38897   A000000 6100    200 944625
38897   A000000 6100    600 -871968
38897   A000000 9000    200 110713
38897   A000000 9000    600 -8202
38897   A000000 10100   100 9159677
38897   A000000 10100   200 14430232
38897   A000000 10100   600 -3577368
```

Thank you for responding.  This data include column 600 which you will note that my query excludes.  It does, however, (I think) illustrate what I would like to achieve: sum the values associated with line 100-9000 columns 100 & 200 to see if their total = the sum of line 10100 column 100 & 200.

Hope this explanation helps.

Al

Comment: When you ask for the sum of lines 00100 - 10099, is that just everything but 10100? Or are there other rows you're factoring out?

Comment: Good Morning  I unfortunately missed your response.  Is there a way to attach a sample of data or do I simply build the example in a response to your question?

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding.  I just pasted a sample of the data as requested.  Had trouble with the format.  Thanks for responding.